# Meta analysis from mean-effectsizes for overlapping samples

Tags: r

I run a meta analysis and use the metafor library to calculate fisher z transformed values from correlations.

```
>meta1 <- escalc(ri=TESTR, ni=N, measure="ZCOR", data=subdata2)
```

As some of the studies I include in my meta-analysis, overlap in samples (i.e.  in Study XY, 5 effect-sizes are reported from the same N), I need to calculate means of the standardized z-values. To indicate overlapping samples, I gave all effect sizes IDs (in Excel) which are equal if the samples overlap.

To run the final metaanalysis, I would like R to sum the standardized effect sizes from IDs and calculate means for the final metaanalysis.

So the idea is:

IF Effect_SIZE_ID (a variable) is similar in two lines of my df, then sum both effect sizes and divide it by two (calculate the mean). Provide this result in a new column.

As I am a full newbie, please let me know if you require further specification!
Thank you so much in advance.

LEon

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `summaryBy` command in the `doBy` package.

```
mymean <- summaryBy(SD_effect ~ ID, FUN = mean, data = data)
```

Should work in general (if you provide some sample data it is easy to check if that does what you need).

Comment: Thank you so much! Here is what i produced (works perfectly!)

Comment: overlap<-matrix(unlist(by(subdata3, subdata3$EFFECT_NO, function(x)apply(x,2,mean,na.rm=T))),
 ncol=ncol(subdata3),byrow=T)
overlap <- data.frame(overlap)
names(overlap)<-names(subdata3)
overlap$N <- ceiling(overlap$N)